# webpack 4 unable to implement HMR

Tags: webpack, webpack-hot-middleware

So i'm fairly new to webpack and for the past week i've been struggling to implement it into my project, i used this guide: https://medium.com/@binyamin/creating-a-node-express-webpack-app-with-dev-and-prod-builds-a4962ce51334
i managed to make most of the stuff work but cant make HMR to start working.
I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

this is mine webpack.dev.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
entry: {
    main: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000?reload=true', './src/index.js']
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: "dist",
    overlay: true,
    hot: true,
    stats: {
        colors: true
    }
},    
mode: 'development',
target: 'web',
devtool: '#source-map',
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        {
            // Loads the javacript into html template provided.
            // Entry point is set below in HtmlWebPackPlugin in Plugins 
            test: /\.pug$/,
            use: ["html-loader", "pug-html-loader"]
            //options: { minimize: true }

        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: ['file-loader']
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/html/pugtest.pug", //paima faila
        filename: "index.html",
        excludeChunks: ['server'],
        inject: false
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        template: "./src/css/style.scss",
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),        
 ]
}
```

my server-dev.js file:

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware'
import config from '../../webpack.dev.config.js'
const app = express(),
   DIST_DIR = __dirname,
   HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'),
   compiler = webpack(config)
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
   publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}))
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
   compiler.outputFileSystem.readFile(HTML_FILE, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
    res.set('content-type', 'text/html')
    res.send(result)
    res.end()
   })
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`App listening to ${PORT}....`)
   console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.')
})
```

index.js file:

```
import logMessage from './js/logger'
import './css/style.scss'

// Log message to console
logMessage('A very warm welcome to Expack!!')

// Needed for Hot Module Replacement
if (typeof (module.hot) !== 'undefined') {
   module.hot.accept() // eslint-disable-line no-undef  
}
```

webpack.server.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const SERVER_PATH = (argv.mode === 'production') ?
       './src/server/server-prod.js' :
       './src/server/server-dev.js'
return ({
    entry: {
        server: SERVER_PATH
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },        
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
        __dirname: false, // if you don't put this is, __dirname
        __filename: false, // and __filename return blank or /
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // Need this to avoid error when working with Express
    module: {
        rules: [{
            // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    }
 })
}
```

and my file structure:

```
express-webpack
   /dist
   /node_modules
   /scr
       /css
           style.scss
       /html
           pugtest.pug
       /js
           logger.js
       /server
           server-dev.js
           server-prod.js
       index.js
   .babelrc
   package-lock.json
   package.json
   webpack.dev.config.js
   webpack.prod.config.js
   webpack.server.config.js
```

and my package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode development --config webpack.dev.config.js",
   "buildProd": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js && webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.config.js",
   "start": "nodemon --watch config --watch ./dist/main.css ./dist/server.js"
 },
```